# I want to import a JSON file and in the process use the handler function included in the JSON file.

Tags: json, reactjs

I can't seem to find a way to convert the JSON's value into a function reference. Need help?

I have attached herewith a small code snippet for reference

```
//addButton.json
    "row": [
             {
               "type": "button",
               "name": "Add",
               "label": "add",
               "color": "warning",
               "size": "lg",
               "colsize": "3",
               "onButtonClick": "this.handleAddRequest"
             }
           ]

//    CustomForm.jsx

import addBankApiInfoPage from '../addBankApiInfo.json';
class CustomForm extends React.Component{

handlerFunction = ()=>{
this.map.rowData(row=>{
if (rowData[row].startsWith("this.")) {
    rowData[row] = eval("this" + r[k].substring(4, r[k].length));
}
});
}
```

### Running this code throws error as

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleAddRequest' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (Add.jsx:57), <anonymous>:1:6)
    at Add.jsx:57
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Add.jsx:48
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Add.jsx:45
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at new Add (Add.jsx:3
```

Comment: If you're just trying to store the name of the function you want to call as a callback and then reference it. Drop the "this." from within the json declaration and in your code you can iterate through the rows and do: `this[row[i].onButtonClick]`

Comment: @KyleRichardson Thank you. But doing this[row[i].onButtonClick] shows up as undefined in the console

Comment: You would have to remove the `'this.'` from the string stored in the JSON, of the `onButtonClick` property.

Answer (score 0):

### 1) Arrow functions do not bind the `this`

Your problem is almost certainly in that arrow functions do not bind the containing object to `this`.

```
class Good {
  meth(){return this}
}
class Good {
  meth: function self(){return this}
}
class Bad {
  meth: ()=>{return this} //will be undefined
}
```

### 2) There is no point in doing `eval`.

There's no need to do `eval("this" + r[k].substring(4, r[k].length))`

1. `eval` should be avoided whenever possible
2. you already have `"this"` as part of the string
3. If `.substring` (or `.slice`) with no second argument goes to the ends of the string

In many production environments `eval` will not even be available, since it is a very common cause for security vulnerability, and also has poor performance and tooling.
In your case, if you want a reference to the running code's `this`, you can do

```
if (rowData[row].startsWith("this.")) {
    rowData[row] = this[r[k].substring(4)]
}
```

If you want a method bound to the `this` target, that you can then call from anywhere, and not just the function in that parameter, you can bind it one of these two ways:

```
if (rowData[row].startsWith("this.")) {
    rowData[row] = this[r[k].substring(4)].bind(this)
}
// OR
if (rowData[row].startsWith("this.")) {
    rowData[row] = () => this[r[k].substring(4)] // the `handlerFunction`'s `this` is captured by the closure
}
```

PS: even `.bind` can't put `this` in an arrow function.

```
console.log((()=>this).bind(1)())
VM3283:1 Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}
console.log((function(){return this}).bind(1)())
VM3362:1 Number {1}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But then, doing this[r[k].substring(4)].bind(this) gives 'undefined' in the console

Comment: @bijays do you get the function you are looking for if you do `console.log(this[r[k].substring(4)])` ?

Comment: yes i do have the handler function as `'this.hadleAddRequest'` assigned to `r[k]` but when console logging it returns as `undefined`